# C# with Mono and tasks/msgbox error

Tags: forms, mono, task

I experimenting with using my c# program on Linux with Mono (5.10) but as soon as I start a task and show a msgbox the program shuts down without any error message, is there a problem using form stuff from the task?

Here is the relevant code executed from a button on the windows form:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Hello);
        });
```

Comment: Your code simply shows an exception of this FAQ, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/#my-multithreaded-application-crashes-or-locks-up So it is already answered.

Comment: Ok thanks, the hole thing seem to be a bit buggy so I did not feel that it would be worth the time to make it work, I will stick with Win7 in kiosk mode.